# Why decoherence?

Tags: decoherence

Why do we study decoherence?

I mean the postulates of quantum mechanics agree with experiments perfectly and we all know how a superposition state looks like, for example the spin-z up state is superposition of spin-x up and down state. The nature isn't deterministic, we've figured that out from careful experiments. At large scales these non deterministic nature average out by Heisenberg's uncertainity principle and expectation values which is what we ultimately observe for big objects.

Then why do we study decoherence? What problems does it solve?

Comment: Suppose I have a quantum system $S$ in my lab. When left alone, the system evolves according to Schrodinger's equation. However, if I measure the system, then according to the so-called postulates of quantum mechanics, the system collapses to some state; this does not follow the Schrodinger equation. Now suppose you observe me and $S$ as a closed quantum system. When I make my measurement of $S$ and $S$ collapses, then at that moment Schrodinger's equation *fails* from your point of view even though you didn't make a measurement. The "postulates" of quantum mechanics are not self consistent.